# Conditionally adding with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need add a set of numbers of the next form: http://jsfiddle.net/XxrCZ/1/
The Total must be the sum of only enabled (by checkbox) numbers...

I tried with this code, and adding this condition:

```
if ( $(this).is('[type=text]') && parseInt( $(this).val() ) %% $(this).disabled==false )




function sumar()
    {    var total = 0;
         var i = 0;       
        $("#frm input").each( function()
        {
            if ( $(this).is('[type=text]') && parseInt( $(this).val() )  )
            {

                total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
                i++;
            }

        });

        document.frm.total.value = total;

    }
```

Please could somebody help me with it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;
$('input[type="text"]:enabled').each(function(){
   var v = Number($(this).val());
   sum += v;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/XxrCZ/2/) - I added a calculate button just to trigger a recalculation after enabling check boxes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to trigger the recalculation when change the check boxes state.

Comment: +1.  This is why I love jQuery!  It makes stuff like this so clear and concise.